# Sci Tick Label Number Format same magnitude

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

I'm trying to plot an tikzplotlib export with large numbers on the y axis. I'd like to format them as `/pgf/number format/sci`, which works so far. However, I'd like the numbers to all have the same magnitude 10^6 and on top of that *not* show that multiplier, as I include it into the y label. So the ticks should go from 0.2 to 1.2, without the *10^6 part. I tried to understand Section 97 (pp. 1051-1056) of the PGF manual, but it is quite overwhelming and I didn't get further than this MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,shapes,arrows.meta,chains}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
    % This file was created by tikzplotlib v0.9.4.
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[
            tick align=inside,
            tick pos=left,
            y tick label style={
                /pgf/number format/sci
            },
            scaled ticks=false,
            x grid style={black},
            xlabel={X Label},
            xmin=-0.5, xmax=4.5,
            xtick style={color=black},
            xtick={0,1,2,3,4},
            xticklabels={4,5,7,10,14},
            y grid style={black},
            ylabel={Y Label ($\times 10^6$)},
            ymin=44166.725, ymax=1328895.775,
            ytick style={color=black}
            ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the plot:
[image: the plot]

I'm sure I'm just missing one tiny command in the `y tick label style`, but I can't figure out which one. I am thankful for any help!